# Spring 3.2 PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer with JBoss EAP 6.2

Tags: java, spring, jboss-eap-6

I want Spring to check for system properties in JBoss EAP 6.2 (which uses JBoss AS 7.2) first and then properties that are located inside the jar.

I tried

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:xxx.properties" />
```

But this uses the properties in the jar not the system properties from JBoss.
I also tried

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:xxx.properties" system-properties-mode="OVERRIDE" />
```

Which should be using the old PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer, but this also still uses the properties in the jar. I also tried to set the 3.0 (instead of 3.2) spring xsd but to no avail.

So how can I let Spring first check the properties in JBoss and then in the jar?

EDIT: I tried to replace OVERRIDE with the other options (ENVIRONMENT, NEVER and FALLBACK), but I always end up with a value defined in local properties.

Comment: Are you really sure that `system properties` contains desired `key`?

Comment: Yes, because when i remove a key from local properties, I see the value defined in the system properties.

Comment: Well, you might have a duplicate configuration for `<context:property-placeholder>` and it is after that one with `OVERRIDE`.

Comment: I'd say the problem is not with Spring, the problem is that you never exposed the system properties to your application in the first place. How are you doing that? Also, EAP 6.2 does not use JBoss AS 7.2, it uses JBoss AS 7.3. EAP 6.1 uses JBoss AS 7.2.

Comment: @ArtemBilan Thanks for your comments, it helped me to the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Artem Bilan's comments, i searched again (just to make sure, there are no duplicates) and found a class that loads the same properties, but within Java (`Properties.load()`). This causes to override the `system properties` i was trying to load via Spring.

Answer (score 1):

To expose properties files to applications, we have done the following:

- Created a `JBoss` module in a directory struction called `com/ourcompany/configuration/main` and placed it along with all the other `JBoss` modules (in the modules directory).
- Created a module.xml in that directory.
- Placed all our *.properties files in that directory.
- Created the following in standalone.xml (the `JBoss` configuration file) to make the configuration directory visible to all our applications, and to avoid a jboss-deployment-structure.xml file for every application.

Then all properties are on the classpath, as expected.

module.xml:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.ourcompany.configuration">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="."/>
    </resources>
</module>
```

standalone.xml:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.1">
    <global-modules>
        <module name="com.ourcompany.configuration" slot="main"/>
    </global-modules>
</subsystem>
```

Comment: Nice workaround to the problem that all system-properties should be in standalone.xml. +1